# Getting rid of #REF! errors on a dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with the following format

Column A - Names

Column B - Product

Column C - Amount of product

Column D - Town

Column E - Formula (=rows($D$2;D168) this gets me a number in order.

Column F - Formula (=if(sheet2!$D$2=B2,E2,"")

Column G - Formula (=iferror(small($F$2:F2)),"")

There are 180 names in the list and maybe more later

and i have this in one sheet and on the second sheet have the following format

Column B - list of product names in sorted order
Column D - Dropbox with the product name.

Column F - Client name {Formula =iferror(index(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$182,Sheet1!$G4,columns(Sheet1!$A$2:A2)),"")

Column G - Column I has the same formula in it.

When i click on the dropdown it does put the information in sheet 2, but if there is only prints the info of that selection and if there is no more info i get #REF! in the other boxes, is there any way of getting rid of this error please?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get rid of the error? And it would be better, if you could simply share your sheet or a dummy copy of it.

Comment: It returns the number 1 and counts down till end of list.

Comment: here is the dummy sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1njhPc53tyX9uXEajRo5jh_2ehFaahYdEVftkqPXOKa8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what your desired outcome should be so I'm taking a guess with this:

[Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d-VD_yFk1xAAwDctmDNaERj3QXtpCo9a8PuVyICEd0g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I want it to list the client name, product, monies and product name i have tried the formula on the dummy spreadsheet on my sheet and i get the error #REF!

Comment: Yes, you have to delete all the other formulas in the other cells. The error tells you 'Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in xxx cell' i.e. delete whatever information is in xxx cell to allow the formula to write into it.

Comment: I have got rid of the formulas in the other cells and still get the #ref error